# Scrapy - Can't locate xpath element

Tags: python, web-scraping, xpath, scrapy

I have just started with Scrapy. I want to **scrape** the all job title from [this page](https://www.pracuj.pl/praca/it%20-%20rozw%c3%b3j%20oprogramowania;cc,5016/%c5%82%c3%b3dzkie;r,5?rd=0) and save it in CSV file. But when I run the command:

> scrapy crawl jobscraper -o file.csv

It made an empty file. What am I doing wrong?

```
import scrapy


class JobScraper(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "jobscraper"
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.pracuj.pl/praca/it%20-%20rozw%c3%b3j%20oprogramowania;cc,5016/%c5%82%c3%b3dzkie;r,5?rd=0',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for offer in response.xpath('//div[contains(@class, "offer__info")]'):
            data = {
                'title': offer.xpath('//a[@class="offer-details__title-link]').extract_first()
            }
            yield data
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
offer.xpath('//a[@class="offer-details__title-link]')
```

isn't a valid XPath expression. You forgot the double quote at the end:

```
offer.xpath('//a[@class="offer-details__title-link"]')
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for that, but still I cant generate a CSV file with data.

Comment: @Kacper_Te - I just realized that I put the double quote in the wrong spot. Does it work now?

Comment: It doesnt. Still empty csv file.

Comment: Ok, I have to switch on USER_AGENT  in file Settings. It's works now.